# Leaflet: How can I render my own tiles for intermediate (based on < 256x256 pixel tiles) zoom levels?

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, zoom, jvectormap

I use Leaflet for most work. Leaflet's default zoom levels use 256x256 pixel tiles. Often this does not allow me to focus nicely on regions, because I cannot set intermediate values in Leaflet's default zoom method; only integers work.

If I knew how to render my own tiles (e.g. 100x100 pixel tiles as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154295/adding-an-extra-zoom-levels-in-leaflet-maps), though I did not understand), I could still use Leaflet. Since I do not, I am considering switching to jvectormaps, but it seems to lack a good documentation.

**Problems:**

- *I cannot zoom to an intermediate level using Leaflet's default zoom and scale methods.*
- *I do not know how to render my own tiles.*
- *If it would help any, I do not understand the Leaflet documentation to create custom layer: [http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#gridlayer](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#gridlayer_)*

**Question 1:** How can I use intermediate (between 256x256 pixel tile size) zoom levels in Leaflet?

**Question 2:** Can you recommend any open-source web-mapping library which offers detailed (smaller than 256x256 pixel) pre-rendered tiles (other than jvectormap)?

Comment: aren't the tiles dependent on the service/server you use not the framework?

Comment: Yeah, most web map libraries (at least leaflet and openlayers, the ones I know of) are able to load tiles of arbitrary size, and even render vector tiles.

Comment: I hope with my edit it is now clearer. Thanks iant♦ and IvanSanchez. Yes, my problem is not with Leaflet, just with its default of using 256x256 pixel tiles for zoom levels. I would like to retain Leaflet for my work, but I do not know how to create AND use arbitrary size tiles. Please help

Comment: I suggest you research into the `zoomSnap` option of `L.Map`, and the `tileSize` option of `L.TileLayer`/`L.GridLayer`. I do not know if you need more granularity of the zoom levels, request smaller tiles, or something else.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I do not want to get too close on zoom level 5 or not close enough on level 4, for example. I hope this makes sense. Sorry, I cannot describe this better

Answer (score 1):

I want to thank IvanSanchez for the help. I was working in Leaflet 0.7.7 which did not have a zoomSnap option.

When defining `L.Map`, one can get between-integer zoom levels by defining a `zoomSnap` factor between 0 and 1 (being the default), as IvanSanchez suggested. Nota bene: This was not available in 0.7.7. And it's awesome